# How to check the number of parameters in Mozilla's DeepSpeech model?

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

I failed to find a simple way to print out how many parameters in the model and proposals to print it in release notes did not find the warm welcome:

https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/344
https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/3392

How many parameters in DeepSpeech 0.8.2 and 0.9.0 models?

PS: [thread on discourse.mozilla](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-many-parameters-in-deepspeech-0-8-2-and-0-9-0-models/69997)

Comment: From discourse link above: "The English models have 47224861 parameters and the Chinese model in 0.9.0 has 47689984 parameters."

Answer (score 2):

Great question, but just for reference, as many people look at the answers first:

The English models have 47224861 parameters and the Chinese model in 0.9.0 has 47689984 parameters.

Expanding on that, DeepSpeech can best be measured by the n_hidden value which indicates the layer width of the model and the number of hours trained.

Usually, you get faster and better answers for DeepSpeech on their [Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org).